# Find and replace a word in several text files with Java?

Tags: java

How can I find and replace a word in several text files, using Java?

Here's how I do it for a single `String`...

```
public class ReplaceAll {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "We want replace replace word from this string";  
        str = str.replaceAll("replace", "Done");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `FileUtils` from [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```
String[] files = { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };
for (String file : files) {
    File f = new File(file);
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("filename.txt"));
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, content.replaceAll("hello", "world"));
}
```

Comment: Is this code ok?  
import java.io.File;

public class FindNReplace
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   String[] files = { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt" };
for (String file : files)
{
    File f = new File(file);
    String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("filename.txt"));
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, content.replaceAll("hello", "world"));
 }
 }
}

Comment: sorry i don't know how to answer

Comment: it seems i can't answer to myself coze i'm new here,

Comment: OK here is the error code : run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not yet implemented
        at findnreplace.FileUtils.readFileToString(FileUtils.java:17)
        at findnreplace.FindNReplace.main(FindNReplace.java:13)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Are you using version 2.1. This method is definitely implemented.

Answer (score 2):

You can read in the file using a FileReader wrapped by a BufferedReader, pulling it in line by line, perform the same replace on the string that you show in your question, and write it back out to a new file.

Comment: Not if you want to replace for instance `"\r\n"` with `"\n"`.

Comment: @aioobe I don't see why that'd be especially problematic. Obviously if you need to replace something that may be longer than one line, it's a bit more complicated, but still better than having to have the whole file in memory at once.

Comment: i just want to know what library i have to add to program

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code: Hope it helps!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class TestIO {

 static StringBuilder sbword = new StringBuilder();
 static String dirname = null;
 static File[] filenames = null;
 static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    boolean fileread = ReadFiles();

    sbword = null;
    System.exit(0);



}
private static boolean ReadFiles() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    System.out.println("Enter the location of folder:");


    File file = new File(sc.nextLine());
    filenames = file.listFiles();
    String line = null;

    for(File file1 : filenames ){
    System.out.println("File name" + file1.toString());
    sbword.setLength(0); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));

    line = br.readLine();

    while(line != null){
        System.out.println(line);
        sbword.append(line).append("\r\n");
        line = br.readLine();
        }

    ReplaceLines();
    WriteToFile(file1.toString());

    }

    return true;    
}

private static void ReplaceLines(){
    System.out.println("sbword contains :" + sbword.toString());
    System.out.println("Enter the word to replace from each of the files:");
    String from = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the new word");
    String To = sc.nextLine();

    //StringBuilder sbword = new StringBuilder(stbuff);
    ReplaceAll(sbword,from,To);



}
private static void ReplaceAll(StringBuilder builder, String from, String to){
    int index = builder.indexOf(from);
    while(index != -1){
        builder.replace(index, index + from.length(), to);
        index += to.length();
        index = builder.indexOf(from,index);
    }
}
private static void WriteToFile(String filename) throws IOException{
   try{
    File file1 = new File(filename);
    BufferedWriter bufwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file1));
    bufwriter.write(sbword.toString());
    bufwriter.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Error occured while attempting to write to file: " +     e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

}