# to replace a word from data accessed from file

Tags: java, file

My job is to replace all the occurences of **Bond** with **Hound**. I have tried the  following code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class myTry {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\KingKong\\Desktop\\WorkSpace\\Victory\\src\\test2.txt";
        FileReader f = null;
        StringTokenizer str = null;
        String temp = "";
        try {
            f = new FileReader(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f);
        try {
            temp = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        str = new StringTokenizer(temp);
        String token = "";
        System.out.println(str);
        while(str.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            token = str.nextToken();
            if(token.equals("Bond"))
            {
                token.replace("Bond","Hound");
            }
        }
        String newMod = str.toString();
        System.out.println(newMod);
        System.out.println(str);

    }
}
```

But it gives me the output (through the console) via the print statements as:

```
java.util.StringTokenizer@4d24bd93
java.util.StringTokenizer@4d24bd93
java.util.StringTokenizer@4d24bd93
```

What does this mean? My logic is 
 - to access the file, 
 - read the data into a string tokenizer object, 
 - check Token by Token whether there is any "Bond" in the token, 
 - if yes Change it.

Thanks for the formatting @kgdesouz
Moreover i dropped the ideat of using the String Tokenizer.What i wanted to do is done by the normal String Class as it is.Here is the code below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class myTry {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\KingKong\\Desktop\\WorkSpace\\Victory\\src\\test2.txt";
        FileReader f = null;
        StringTokenizer str = null;
        String temp = "";
        try {
            f = new FileReader(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(f);
        try {
            temp = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
        String newMod = temp.replaceAll("Bond","Hound");

        System.out.println(newMod);



    }
}
```

It gives the output

```
Bond is a bad boy.Bond goes to temple EveryDay.
Hound is a bad boy.Hound goes to temple EveryDay.
```

Cheers!!

Comment: You're attempting to print a `StringTokenizer` instance; what do you expect to happen? And that's ignoring that you really should be using `StringTokenizer` in modern code, as per the Javadocs.

Comment: When you're replacing this text, do you have to write it back to the file?

Comment: Note that **token.replace("Bond","Hound")** does not modify the token, but instead returns the modified string, which you are discarding.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. A quick search yielded **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779265/find-and-replace-a-word-in-several-text-files-with-java)**. Note, in general, please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Makoto..yes i a supposed to write it back.But i was making sure the string i write back was properly changed.

Comment: @Keith..then should i not be using the StringTokenizer class at all??

Answer (score 0):

You should use available API for this solution.

Apache Commons_IO is the best for file handling .

See the example for your question.

This will convert any "Bond" string in the file with "Hound" and write it back to the file.

This will over-write it. More information [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/)

```
package com.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class TestFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("d:/test.txt");
        String input = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
        String output = input.replaceAll("Bond", "Hound");
        FileUtils.write(file, output);
    }

}
```